# Too many iron golems in snapshot 19w13b

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started my game near a village and started fixing and improving the village, I got my first golem to spawn but after 2 hours I had over 20 golems. what made this happen? So I killed 1/4th of them and now the villagers don't like me.

Answer (score 2):

Klling golems obviously angers the villagers, that's normal behavior. The abnormal golem spawning is a bug, already reported at bugs.mojang.com. – [Vladislav Toncharov](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/199213/vladislav-toncharov) in [a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348422/too-many-iron-golems-in-snapshot-19w13b#comment490190_348422)